# New project in Visual Studio Team Services is following item numbering from a deleted one

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Sorry the poor English.

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services for a first time, and I follow the guided tour where I created three work items as example. Basic conceptions learned, I then deleted these first example work items and started to Create my own work items. Their numbering was sequential to the three first ones.

I managed to delete my Project to start a new one. I was think a new Project will start its work items from number 1 onwards, but the numbering from the deleted one is being used. I tried creating the repository with another Project name but no success.

I wasn't able to find how this is occurring, and it's very annoying to me. Someone has any idea about what's going on and how to correct this behavior (unless this is a feature)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this VSTS or your own TFS?

Comment: @DaveShaw, I use VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS you have a Collection Database, that has a WorkItem table, all Work Item Id's are sequential in that table. A Collection contain one or more Team Projects. To reset the numbers you would have to create a new Collection.

In VSTS Collections are not a concept that you can manage, you have an account instead, you would probably have to delete and re-create your account - I don't think there is any way to create a new Collection in your account - I may be wrong, I'm only a personal user of VSTS.

I wouldn't worry too much about what ID's each work item has. I don't think it matters that much, you will soon lose control of them. Every WI you create has a new incremental ID, you you get Bug #1, Test Case #2, PBI #3, and so on. If you have >1 Team Project you will also end up with that taking ID's from you.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveShaw. I recreated my account and all seems fine. My annoyance is aspie-related, but I'll try to maintain it at bay. Again, thanks.